# How to get data from a hook?

Tags: extension, hook

How do I get the last "ID" (row) created after using the "channel_form_submit_entry_end" hook? Can the hook send me the "ID"? EE5

Comment: Are you looking for the ID of the entry which was just created by the channel form submission?

Comment: Yes. The ID of the entry created by the channel form submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of hook "channel_form_submit_entry_end" it is using the Channel Form Class so $obj->entry['entry_id'] a class property which is not available.

Good news is you can use the method $obj->entry('entry_id') to retrieve the entry which is one of available methods from Channel_form_lib

Answer (score 0):

If you do a dump of the argument which that hooks accepts, you'll see it should contains the `entry_id`. I can't recall exactly what the structure looks like (it might just be `$obj->entry_id` or `$obj['entry_id']`), but do this to find out:

```
function channel_form_submit_entry_end($obj)
{
    exit(var_dump($obj));
}
```

Comment: I used 

my_function($obj){
exit(var_dump($obj));
}

But the entry_id is not there or set

Comment: Should be `$obj->entry['entry_id']` ... is the submission completing successfully (showing up in the database)?

Comment: Yes. It is being created.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type EllisLab\ExpressionEngine\Model\Channel\ChannelEntry this is the error I get when I try to call $ojb->entry['entry_id']